# Gaining more baking rights

Tags: baking, kiln

Is there any way to improve Kiln node to have more baker rights? Are there some best practices to have more baker rights?

Any informative link is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kiln as a software is not meant to give you more baking rights. It is just a software meant to allow you to interface nicely with the network and perform your baker duties.

In tezos as a baker you get one baking right per roll that you own or have been delegated to. One roll is 8000XTZ as per the Babylon protocol. If you want more rights you need to own more or find people to people delegate to you so you bake on their behalf.

For more information about the Liquid Proof-Of-Stake protocol (LPOS) please read the official documentation

https://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html